# Ubuntu won't load GUI

Tags: graphics

I just bought a Toshiba L75D-A7283 laptop. It has an AMD Radeon HD8330 graphics card in it. Windows 8 is awful, so I figured I would give Linux a try before installing Windows 7.

I'm clueless when it comes to Linux, so anybody know why on this laptop it won't load the GUI but stays at the command line? Also it wouldn't load the GUI off the CD when selecting Try Ubuntu before installing.

Comment: Please specify the version you are using and possibly a photo of what you are facing

Comment: Try the command `startx`

Comment: What I don't understand: why did you expect a successful install when the "Try it" already couldn't load the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

To get everything working in Ubuntu 13.04 , it looks like you need the 3.10 linux kernel for the wireless network, which requires the 13.8 beta catalyst driver from AMD. Then you have to modify /etc/rc.local to fix a permissions issue with /proc/ati.

What I did was:
Install the 3.10.7 kernel from 
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.10.7-saucy/
using the 64 bit directions from 
http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-kernel-3-10-7-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-debian-and-derivates/

Then install the following package
Sudo apt-get install dkms

Make the packages for the 13.8 drive, similar to section 3 of
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

Modify /etc/rc.local

sudo cp /etc/rc.local /etc/rc.local.original
sudo pico /etc/rc.local

and insert the line "chmod -R 777 /proc/ati" before the "exit 0" line

Hit ctrl-o to save
Hit ctrl-x to exit

I think that was everything